# How do I escape the ',' character in System.out.format?

Tags: java, formatting

I want to output two numbers separated by a comma using `System.out.format`. I tried to escape it with %, but it didn't help.

Target output should be in the form of (0.92,0.91)

```
System.out.format("(%.2f% %.2f)%n", x, fx);
                         ^--- I want to add a ',' character here
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to escape a comma in the format.  Just place a comma in the format, without a percent sign next to it.

```
System.out.format("(%.2f,%.2f)%n", x, fx);
```